# How to check for internet before starting the player

Tags: ios, avplayer, reachability

I have a code to play online media. I have implemented internet checking while the song is being played. That means, if the internet goes while the song is being played., it will show an alert. But the problem is, if I am not connected to internet, and then I open the app, if I press play button, it does not check for the internet and does not show the alert. How to check for internet before player starts playing the song.? If no internet, the player should show the alert instead of pause button.

here is my code section:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
CM_EXPORT const CMTime kCMTimeZero;
@interface FirstViewController ()
@end


@implementation FirstViewController
@synthesize  metadatas;
@synthesize toggleButton;
@synthesize slider;
@synthesize mpVolumeView = _mpVolumeView;
@synthesize viewVolume;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    toggleIsOn=TRUE;

    MPVolumeView *volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:self.viewVolume.bounds] ;

    [self.viewVolume addSubview:volumeView];

    [volumeView sizeToFit];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

}

-(IBAction)playButtonPressed:(id)sender
{

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setBool:TRUE forKey:@"FirstPlay"];
    [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"alertShown"];

        if(toggleIsOn){

        toggleIsOn=!toggleIsOn;

        player = nil;
        NSString *stringurl = @"";
        stringurl = @"http://majestic.wavestreamer.com:6221/listen.pls";
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringurl];
        asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
        playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
        player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
        player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
        [playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"timedMetadata" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
        [playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
        [player play];
        isPlaying = TRUE;
        NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
        [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(audioSessionInterrupted:) name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification object:nil];

        [self.toggleButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reload.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    }
    else {

        [self.toggleButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"playMusic.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self->player.rate=0.0;
        toggleIsOn=!toggleIsOn;
        isPlaying = FALSE;
    }

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setBool:TRUE forKey:@"alertShown"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkNetworkStatus:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

    internetReachable = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    [internetReachable startNotifier];

    // check if a pathway to a random host exists
    hostReachable = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.apple.com"];
    [hostReachable startNotifier];


}
```

**Code to check network**

```
-(void) checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice
{
    // called after network status changes
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    switch (internetStatus)
    {
        case NotReachable:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is down.");
            NSLog(@"%d",[defaults boolForKey:@"alertShown"]);
            BOOL isAlertShown = [defaults boolForKey:@"alertShown"];
            if(isAlertShown)
           {
               isPlaying = false;
               [self showAlert];
           }

            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is working via WIFI.");
            if(self.alert)
            {
                [self.alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
                self.alert = nil;
            }

            BOOL isFirstTimePlayed = [defaults boolForKey:@"FirstPlay"];
            if(!isPlaying)
            {
            if(isFirstTimePlayed)
            {
                [self playButtonPressed:nil];
            }
            }

            break;
        }
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
        {
            NSLog(@"The internet is working via WWAN.");
            if(isPlaying)
            {
            [self playButtonPressed:nil];
            }
            if(self.alert)
            {
                [self.alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
                self.alert = nil;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

   }


-(void)showAlert
{
    //NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    //[defaults setBool:FALSE forKey:@"alertShown"];

    //alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Alert" message: @"You have lost data connectivity. Please wait while we try to establish the connection again." delegate: nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    //[alert show];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setBool:FALSE forKey:@"alertShown"];

    self.alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert"
                                                                    message:@"You have lost data connectivity. Please wait while we try to establish the connection again."
                                                                   delegate:self
                                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [self.alert show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
        if(!isPlaying)
        {
            [player pause];
            [self.toggleButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"playMusic.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}    
@end
```

The function to check internet should execute before playing the song also.

Comment: why put so much code??? i really doubt anyone would examine it all. you should post only relevant code

Comment: Holy code-dump, Batman! Even the Bat Computer will have trouble reading all that...

Comment: -(IBAction)playButtonPressed:(id)sender check if net is working then play the song else generate alert. your code so big..

Comment: If you have code to check for a drop in the internet connection, then why can't you use the same logic before playing the song?

Comment: Please see the updated code. i am trying to check. I am new to iOS.. i am unable to check it before playing the song. Please just tell me where to put the condition to check internet before playing song and show alert if no internet.